# Symfony : How to set translation domain of entity constraint annotation

Tags: symfony

In Symfony entity constraint can be specified via annotation like this :

```
 /**
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="author.name.not_blank")
 */
protected $name;
```

The default translation domain is `validators`.
I would like to know how to specify an other translation domain than the default one only for a set of validations like this one.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that **by default you can't**, because there not exist a `translation_domain` option to be able to set it directly in the entity constraint Annotation and unless you have a very particular use case there is a lot of work to do to implement yourself this missed option.

If you take a look at the source code of the Symfony [Validator Component](https://github.com/symfony/validator) you will see that the default translation domain was set by the [ExecutionContextFactory](https://github.com/symfony/validator/blob/master/Context/ExecutionContextFactory.php). The context then is inherited by all constraint validator, so you can change it only inside the validator itself, and more precisely in the `validate` method, that you have to implement in each validator, like in the [`NotBlankValidator`](https://github.com/symfony/validator/blob/master/Constraints/NotBlankValidator.php#L26):

```
public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
{
    if (!$constraint instanceof NotBlank) {
        throw new UnexpectedTypeException($constraint, 
        __NAMESPACE__.'\NotBlank');
    }
    if (false === $value || (empty($value) && '0' != $value)) {
        $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message)
            ->setParameter('{{ value }}', $this->formatValue($value))
            ->setCode(NotBlank::IS_BLANK_ERROR)
            ->setTranslationDomain('your_trans_domain') #<--- THIS LINE
            ->addViolation();
    }
}
```

So, the most simple option (*specially if you need this only for a few validators*) is to build your [own validators](https://symfony.com/doc/2.4/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html) to be able to set the translation domain like the previous example.

If you need to change it for a third party validator just build your own validator and add a service alias to the third part ones:

```
App\NotBlankValidator:
    tags: [validator.constraint_validator]
    alias: The\Third\Part\Validator\Namespace
```

Anyway could be useful to know you can change the translation domain globally for all validators.

**Symfony <=3.3 (and 3.4 if you don't use Flex)**

In the `config.yml` file(inside `config` folder):

```
framework:
    validation: { translation_domain: your_custom_trans_domain_string }
```

**Symfony >3.4 (and also 3.4 if you use Flex)**

In the `framework.yaml` file (inside `config/packages` folder):

```
framework:
    validation: { translation_domain: your_custom_trans_domain_string }
```

Comment: Ok thanks but how to change it only for this validation?

Comment: For what I remember now you can't because there not exist a `translation_domain` option to set it directly in the annotation assert, but I never seen using a different translation domain only for ONE validator.

Comment: @Tsounabe Anyway (_I can't test it now_) just try with `@Assert\NotBlank(message="author.name.not_blank", translation_domain="your_domain")` or `@Assert\NotBlank(message="author.name.not_blank", domain="your_domain")` and let me know if my memory start to lacks something :-) **PS: and remember to clear the cache after any change!**

Comment: When i say only for this validation it is an example. I want to know if it possible to change this translation domain. I tried with domain and translation_domain but it does not work. :/ Thanks

Comment: So my mind remembered well. I updated the answer :-) just accept it.

Comment: I will accept it when i will know there is no solution.

Comment: I think is passed enough time to understand there isn't other solutions, don't you?

Answer (score 0):

```
Create a validators catalog file in the translations/ directory:


`<!-- translations/validators.en.xlf -->
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xliff version="1.2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <file source-language="en" datatype="plaintext" original="file.ext">
        <body>
            <trans-unit id="author.name.not_blank">
                <source>author.name.not_blank</source>
                <target>Please enter an author name.</target>
            </trans-unit>
        </body>
    </file>
</xliff>`
```

Comment: Ok but how to specify an other translation domain name than validators? PS: I updated my question